# Issues in Integrating Airpush ads

Tags: android, ads, airpush

I have integrated the Airpush SDK from the following 
[documentation](http://manage.airpush.com/docs/index.php?title=Android_In-App_SDK_6.0_Documentation)

the SDK could be seen in the libraries folder but whenever I add the XML ad, i get an Error:

> Multiple annotations found at this line:
>     - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'animation' in package       ''
>
> - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'test_mode' in package       ''
> - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'canShowMR' in package       ''
> - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'banner_type' in package     ''
> - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'placementType' in package       ''

I get an error while Integrating the ads through java code too

Comment: can you please provide airpush ad sdk link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to place the mraid_attrs.xml file into your app's res > values folder. This file is included within the SDK download.

Comment: thanks, that worked.. could you give a hint for the java ad too

Comment: use context instead of activity like ApSmartWall apSmartWall=new ApSmartWall(mContext, null); or ApSmartWall apSmartWall=new ApSmartWall(mainActivity.this, null);

Comment: still getting the error, "APSmartWall cannot be resolved into a type"

Answer (score -1):

looks like you are using their out-app sdk, try replacing APSmartWall with Airpush, if it's working then you are using out-app SDK.

Comment: I used the In-App SDK, but it still seems fishy. I switched to Admob and It is working Okay